# How to use the smallest piece of soap for bathing?

Tags: personal-care, bathroom

We start soap usage with a bar that is handy to use. As the soap bar consumption starts, it starts getting smaller day by day.

When it is very small it is very difficult to pick and apply on the skin due to its greasiness.

What are the way through which it can be handled easily to consume till its last part ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For many years, I've opened a new bar when the old one got too small -- and, after washing (with both bars wet) pressed the new bar onto the old one.  They'll dry enough after the shower to cement together, and then the old bar and the new will handle as one bar.  No waste, no residue, no special handling needed.

Comment: Me too. Works great. Might require more than one shower to get them to adhere. I typically use 2 bars at all times, one welded together and one new-ish.

Answer (score 4):

My husband uses the new cake of soap until it is a small slither.  I put the slithers into a used liquid soap container, add hot water and shake well.  I use the liquid soap thus produced for washing at the handbasin, and for dishwashing and sink cleaning in the kitchen.

Comment: Does that stay as liquid soap or transforms back to solid?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a onion bag (nylon vegetable mesh produce bag) to put the soap into it and tie a knot off the bag. It will have longer functional use of soap.

[Source](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Soap-Holder-out-of-a-Bag-of-Onions/)

2. Put a Bottle cap onto the soap when you start using the soap. Till the end it will act like a holder to your soap. But this has a catch - the cap will consume small amount of soap that is equal to its internal open area.

Answer (score 2):

I collect the little slivers until there are a dozen or so of them. Periodically I grind up the slivers with a salad shooter or just grate them with a grater.  Then I cut the bottom off an oval plastic bottle to use as a soap mold.   Take the grated pieces and put them in the bottle bottom.  Add some water to the mix.  Then put it in the microwave --- about 10 to 15 seconds at a time.  The soap will begin to bubble and rise.  Take it out and tamp it down and replace in the microwave and repeat for another 10 seconds.  Do this a few times till the soap will tamp down and the air bubbles are removed (you may need to add a bit more water to get the proper mix).  Then put it all aside to dry out (about a week or so).  When it's dry, take it out of the bottle bottom, and let it dry out another week or so.  Then, use it.

I had about 30 bars of hotel soap collected over the years. I ground them all and made 5 larger bars of soap I'm currently using in the shower every day.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

1. The simplest solution and perhaps the most obvious: Just stick the sliver to the bottom of your next bar. Use a bit of water to seal it. Nothing fancy here, but it totally works.
2. Save the slivers up and then turn them into a brand new bar. Once you’ve collected enough scraps, you can reform them to create an entirely new mutant chimera bar. There are many different ways to do this, all of them relatively easy, each of which involves a slightly different technique. So Google around a bit and find yourself a well-rated recipe.
3. Make a self-soaping cloth by wrapping a small assortment of soap scraps in a wash cloth, and tying it shut with a piece of string to create a sort of sachet. Keep it in the shower for quick and easy scrubbing action.
4. Save your scraps and stuff them into the toe of an old pair of pantyhose, tie it up, and hang it near your outside faucet. This is a great way to guarantee you’ll have soap on-hand for when you’re finishing up a day in the garden, or doing some other outdoor dirty work. Bonus: Like the self-soaping wash cloth, the pantyhose will help to create a lather.
5. You can also use this soap-on-a-rope trick to keep pests like deer away from your garden and fruit trees. As above, just drop a few soap slivers into the toe of an old pair of panty hose, tie it up, and hang it from whatever plant you’re trying to protect. The soapy smell will keep those critters away.
6. Did you know you can make homemade laundry detergent? Place a collection of completely-dried soap scraps into a food processor and grind them to a crumbly powder. In a large bowl, combine 2 parts washing soda, 2 parts borax, and 1 part soap crumbles. Mix thoroughly and store in a mason jar. Use 2 tbsp per load of laundry.
7. You can also turn your old bar soap scraps into brand new liquid hand soap. The process involves cooking down the soap with glycerin and essential oils. It's a bit more work, but it's a fun DIY project.
8. And finally, keep a sliver of soap in your sewing or craft kit. It’s perfect for scoring a seam or otherwise marking the fabric. Since the soap washes out so easily, it makes an ideal replacement for tailor’s chalk.

Answer (score 0):

I lather the soap on my hands and then clean myself with them.  This is instead of trying to rub the bar on my body directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can rub small pieces in the back of your hands. Rougher than the palms. It works ok for hands cleaning.